# Creating Step Builder with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to get ByteBuddy to implement a step builder, given an interface for that builder. I'm stuck on 2 places.

1. How to create a setter that returns the current instance for method chaining?

I started with:

```
.method(ElementMatchers.isSetter())
.intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty());
```

only I'd like to return the current builder instance so we can chain calls like:

```
final Object obj = ...builder().id(100).name("test").build();
```

so instead I created an interceptor like this, which seems like a hack and I'd like to avoid reflection where possible:

```
@RuntimeType
public Object intercept(@RuntimeType Object arg, @This Object source, @Origin Method method)
{
  try
  {
    // Field name is same as method name.
    final Field field = source.getClass().getDeclaredField(method.getName());
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(source, arg);
  }
  catch (Throwable ex)
  {
    throw new Error(ex);
  }

  // Return current builder instance.
  return source;
}
```

2. Is there an easy way to access defined fields on a class I'm defining without reflection?

Currently I add fields to the builder class in a loop and my build method on the builder is intercepted like this:

```
private static final class InterBuilder
{
  private final Collection<String> fields;
  private final Constructor<?> constructor;

  InterBuilder(final Constructor<?> constructor, final Collection<String> fields)
  {
    this.constructor = constructor;
    this.fields = fields;
  }

  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@This Object source, @Origin Method method)
  {
    try
    {
      final Object[] args = Arrays.stream(source.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(f -> this.fields.contains(f.getName()))
        .map(f ->  { try {
          f.setAccessible(true);
          return f.get(source); }
          catch (Throwable ex) { throw new Error(ex); } })
        .toArray();

      // Invoke a constructor passing in the private field values from the builder...
      return this.constructor.newInstance(args);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
      throw new Error(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

I saw the `@FieldValue` annoation. I don't suppose there is something that will give me all fields without knowing their names up front?

The code is a proof of concept at this point. Are there better ways to do what I'm doing here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compose two implementations:

```
FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty().setsArgumentAt(0).andThen(FixedValue.self());
```

This will set the setters first (index 0) argument and then return `this`.

If you wanted to set a field from a `MethodDelegation` without reflection, have a look at `FieldProxy`.

Comment: Thank you! I got this to work with a simple bean setter. What would be the best way to go about implementing a "build"? I would have to access those private fields I just set like: return new Something(this.a, this.b, this.c); Of course since the class I'm creating in the builder is also generated all I have is a Constructor<T>.

Comment: You can invoke a constructor using the MethodCall implementation.

Comment: I ended up discovering "MethodCall.construct(...)", which is what I needed. This is a great tool, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rafael gave me the information I needed to come up with a solution, so the answer credit goes to him, but I wanted to include my solution for anyone else to discover in the future.

```
DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Object.class)
  .implement(interfaces)
  .name(builderClassName);

// Find all of the setters on the builder...  
// Here I'm assuming all field names match setter names like:
//   MyClass x = theBuilder.name("hi").id(1000).isValid(true).build();
final List<Method> setters = ...

for (final Method setter : setters)
{
  // This will define a field and a setter that will set the value and return the current instance.
  builder = builder
    .defineField(setter.getName(), setter.getParameterTypes()[0], Visibility.PRIVATE)
    .define(setter)
    .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofField(setter.getName()).setsArgumentAt(0).andThen(FixedValue.self()));
}

// Find the "build" method on the builder.
final Method buildMethod = ...

// Get a constructor that you want the builder to call and return the new instance.
final Constructor<?> constructor = ...

// Get the field names from the setters.
final List<String> fieldNames = setters.stream()
  .map(Method::getName)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

// This will define a "build" method that will invoke the constructor of some object and
// pass in the fields (in order) of the builder to that constructor.
builder = builder
  .define(buildMethod)
  .intercept(MethodCall.construct(constructor)
    .withField(fieldNames.toArray(new String[fieldNames.size()])));
```